# system pause in c/c++

Tags: c++, c

According to the explanation of this site [don't use system("pause")](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html),
system("pause") will "open an operating system shell (relaunches the O/S in a sub-process)".
what is the meaning of O/S? Operating system?  It would be unbelievably expensive if O/S == Operating system

Comment: Wait... why would being "expensive" even matter? "My program can pause more efficiently than yours!"

Comment: This sounds like an incredible misunderstanding of what an OS is.

Comment: The system command will start another shell. This can cause swapping and other problems, which may make your pause much longer than you intend.

Comment: Stop reading silly webpages written by idiots. But yes, don't use system("pause"), it's never needed.

Comment: I also highly doubt anyone would be using `system("pause")` in a performance critical section of code.  The best argument against it is one of portability.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus It's not always easy to tell if a webpage is silly or written by an idiot. *Someone* needs to point it out if the reader doesn't realize it.

Comment: Hmmm, were you imagining that Windows might spawn a new instance of Windows as a new process (somehow) so that it can then run the 'pause' command?  You are right - that would be crazy.  Generally, the point of avoiding `system("pause")` is that it's not portable.  But it is very convenient when you don't care.

Comment: @Mysticial: Is it about C++? Assume it's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what they meant to put is relaunch the shell in another process.

Comment: That is indeed what they meant, and also what they said. OP did not comprehend well.

Comment: Well, admittedly O/S is not generally used as operating system shell. Their statement "open an operating system shell (relaunches the O/S in a sub-process)" seems a little contradictory unless you interpret O/S as operating system shell.